# gcc with electric fence library does not take effect

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ubuntu, debian

I have written a snippet that has memory problems when dynamically allocating; when compiled with `-lefence` option, it seems that there is no effect. Here is the code segment:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int *a = (int *)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
  for(int i = 0; i <=2; ++i){
    a[i] = i;
    printf ("%d\n",a[i]);
  }

  free(a);
  return 0;
}
```

And the compilation options:

```
gcc -g3 -Wall -std=c99 outOfBound.c -lefence
```

The expected result is that when `a.out` is executed there would be a core dump after `i` is assigned to 2 and `a[i]=i` is invoked.

So Why `-lefence` has no effect?

I have also increased the upper bound in the loop to 9, but there is still no core dump that`electric-fence` invoked. (Actually there is indeed a core dump by default, but this might due to the `MALLOC_CHECK_` env virable since when I `export MALLOC_CHECK_=0`, there would be no more core dump).

**UPDATE**: the whole result of `nm -A a.out` is as below:

```
a.out:08049f28 d _DYNAMIC
a.out:08049ff4 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
a.out:0804864c R _IO_stdin_used
a.out:         w _Jv_RegisterClasses
a.out:08049f18 d __CTOR_END__
a.out:08049f14 d __CTOR_LIST__
a.out:08049f20 d __DTOR_END__
a.out:08049f1c d __DTOR_LIST__
a.out:08048718 r __FRAME_END__
a.out:08049f24 d __JCR_END__
a.out:08049f24 d __JCR_LIST__
a.out:0804a01c A __bss_start
a.out:0804a014 D __data_start
a.out:08048600 t __do_global_ctors_aux
a.out:08048480 t __do_global_dtors_aux
a.out:0804a018 d __dso_handle
a.out:         w __gmon_start__
a.out:080485f2 t __i686.get_pc_thunk.bx
a.out:00000000 a __init_array_end
a.out:00000000 a __init_array_start
a.out:080485f0 T __libc_csu_fini
a.out:08048580 T __libc_csu_init
a.out:         U __libc_start_main
a.out:0804a01c A _edata
a.out:0804a024 A _end
a.out:0804862c T _fini
a.out:08048648 R _fp_hw
a.out:080483b4 T _init
a.out:08048450 T _start
a.out:0804a01c b completed.6159
a.out:0804a014 W data_start
a.out:0804a020 b dtor_idx.6161
a.out:080484e0 t frame_dummy
a.out:         U free
a.out:08048504 T main
a.out:         U malloc
a.out:         U printf
```

(I am using a debian package `electric-fence` on Ubuntu 12.04 32bit, `gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3`)

## Update(20140801):

For `electric-fence` of version `2.2.4` packaged by debian(testing branch, i.e. jessie), it works.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but for me it works as expected (i.e. generates a segfault). However, I used the source from [here](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Debuggers/Electric-Fence-3305.shtml), built it using the Makefile, and also I had to add `-lpthread` to the linker options, otherwise it wouldn't link. Also, I am on Fedora.

Comment: @jogojapan Thanks. There is indeed a possibility that the deb is not packed well.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you are running into this.

> ... it must increase the size of the allocation to a multiple of the
>   word size. In addition, the functions memalign() and valloc() must
>   honor explicit specifications on the alignment of the memory
>   allocation, and this, as well can only be implemented by increasing
>   the size of the allocation. Thus, there will be situations in which
>   the end of a memory allocation contains some padding space, and
>   accesses of that padding space will not be detected, even if they are
>   overruns.

Try exceed the bounds a bit more, and see at what point the overrun detection kicks in.

Comment: Check where you are picking up the definitions for malloc from. They should be coming from -lefence. Use "nm -A <executable> | grep -i malloc".

Comment: What do you mean by say _comming from -lefence_? I checked with `nm -A ./a.out|less` and didn't find any substring like `fence`. So am I using the linkage option the wrong way?

Comment: I am just asking you to confirm that the malloc() definition you are picking up is coming from the -lefence library. Because what you are trying will only work if the correct malloc() definition is being linked in. I am telling you the command you need to execute to find this out. Execute "nm -A a.out | grep -i malloc" and paste result here.

Comment: Just tried it. Seg faults at a[2] for me. Do you get the following line in the output when you run the code "Electric Fence 2.2 Copyright (C) 1987-1999 Bruce Perens <bruce@perens.com>"? That seems to confirm that the right version of malloc() is being used.

Comment: No, no string about `Electric Fence`, the snippet run without any errors and exit. Even the exit status code is `0`.

Comment: So maybe the debian package is not packed well?

Comment: Not sure. All I know is that I get that line printed out when I run the program. It's absence is kind of suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

Once you compile and execute above program without linking it with electric fence library, it may run without any segmentation fault.

So better to link it with electric fence library and then Run it by loading it in gdb giving the following command

```
$ gdb a.out
....
(gdb)run
Starting program: /home/arif/sysprog-2017/processmgmt/nonlocalgoto/a.out 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
  Electric Fence 2.2 Copyright (C) 1987-1999 Bruce Perens <bruce@perens.com>
0
1
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055555555484d in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe228) at temp.c:8
8       a[i] = i;
```

So from above output of gdb you can make out the source line number which is causing the problem if you print the value of i at this instant it will be 2 :)